# ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 after deploying Flask app to gcloud

Tags: python, flask, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm deployed an app to Google Cloud using [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492) tutorial. The app is made using Flask and makes use of flask-sqlalchemy (and thus sqlalchemy).

I can load pages that don't make use of sqlalchemy fine, but pages that do raise a 500 error. The error page shows `ImportError: No module named _sqlite3`.

I suspect it has something to do with me trying to install a Python3 library to gcloud's Python2.7 environment, but I don't know how to fix this. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google's examples here for App Engine Standard, Cloud SQL and Python:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql

There's one for MySQL and another for PostgreSQL.

The tutorial link you shared does not appear to include a database component so I'm assuming you've evolved the example and that you're planning to use Google Cloud SQL database service for your backend.

You're likely missing a Python package that provides SQL connectivity (Google uses [`PyMySQL`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/requirements.txt))